# How to implement jumping in a text-based Python maze game

Tags: python, maze

I am developing a maze game in python where mazes look something like this

```
#########
#   #   #
# # # # #
#x#   # #
#########
```

where `x` is the player and `#` is a wall, and i want to make an obstacle that you can only pass by jumping.

I tried creating a state variable that can be set do default and jumping, and when you press a key the variable changes and the player becomes `X` instead of `x`, and after 1 second it becomes normal again.

I used `time.sleep(1)` as a timer for resetting the player back to default, but i couldn't move while jumping.

Is there a way to jump and move at the same time?

I can show the movement script or anything else if needed.

Comment: We need to see some code (and based on what you said maybe use some threading)

Comment: `time.sleep` is blocking. See [Non-polling/Non-blocking Timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180915/non-polling-non-blocking-timer)

Comment: It kinda works now but instead of jumping for 1 second the player jumps until it moves