# How to make a loop without stopping the code execution

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was making a discord bot and wanted to make a timer, but without using a loop.  The problem with a loop is that it would stop the rest of the circuit until it's done executing the loop. Is there a way to get around this? I did search how to do it, but all of them used `while x > 60` which would not work in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-polling/Non-blocking Timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180915/non-polling-non-blocking-timer)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use threads, and that would look something like this:

```
import threading

def func():
    times = 0
    while times < 10:
        print(times)
        times += 1;

x = threading.Thread(target=func)
x.start()

n = 100

while n < 110:
    n += 1
    print(n)
```

Here both while loops run at the same time