# How can I get the bot to wait for a certain event at the same time, but at the same time communicate with other users?

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram

I use aiogram and I would like to do something like a timer in sleep, but alas, I don't get what I want ...

What I need:
The user waits for 10 seconds to restore health
Then he receives a message from the bot.

Problem:
When you write sleep(10) in the code, the bot falls asleep for all users.
Question:
How to make the bot sleep only with a certain person, and work with others at this time ...

Code example:

```
def sleep_timer(user_id: int, time):
 # here is a code that I do not know how to write (
```

Comment: This answer should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22182149/10276412

Comment: use asyncio.sleep

Comment: Thanks helped Now I will note that the answer helped and I will close the question

Comment: Damn forgot how it's done