# Ignore time.sleep and go with second condition immediately if is meet. Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a problem with my code. I'm writing in python using selenium and I want to create a loop
which will repeatedly refresh the page with `time.sleep(3)` until it meets a condition. The condition is when a button on the page will be clickable then click it immediately.

For now it works like refreshing the page every 3 sec and checking a button, when button is clickable the bot is clicking it but as well with 3 sec delay, I want to do this immediately. For example if the button will be clickable after 1 sec I want to click it after 1 sec.

Someone could help me?

```py
window.get("https://training.openspan.com/login")

while True:
    button = window.find_elements("xpath", '/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/input')
    for item in button:            
        if item.get_attribute('disabled') != "true":
            item.click()
            break
        else:
            window.refresh()
            time.sleep(3) 
            break
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the second `break`?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson removed second break, but nothing changes

Comment: Instead of doing a `sleep` which blocks, something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180915/non-polling-non-blocking-timer) might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a good use case for `WebDriverWait`.
Add the following lines at the top of your code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Then change your code that you wrote in your question to:

```
window.get("https://training.openspan.com/login")

while True:
    try:
        button = WebDriverWait(window, timeout=3, poll_frequency=0.2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "login_button")))
        button.click()
        break # leave while loop
    except TimeoutException:
        window.refresh()
```

This will check every 0.2 seconds if the button is clickable. If this condition is not met within 3 seconds, the `TimeoutException` is fired and it will refresh the page.